# how to parse data with delimiters

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help parsing  this string in sql:

`'ProviderPractice:ONGH_PROFILE_PRACTICE:14758:1194291922^190301^003'`

and get the result as `1194291922^003`

I tried using `substring`, `replace` and `charindex` but did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply `parsename()` function(*which can be used to split strings delimited by at most 3 dot characters* ) two times by replacing punctuations by `dot` characters in the intermediate steps :

```
with t0(str) as
(
 select replace('ProviderPractice:ONGH_PROFILE_PRACTICE:14758:1194291922^190301^003',':','.')
), t1(str) as
(
 select replace(parsename(str,1),'^','.')
   from t0
)   
select concat(parsename(str,3),'^',parsename(str,1)) as "Result"
  from t1;

Result
--------------
1194291922^003
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7d301fa48cdaf94410c8c3611f60cc74)</kbd>

P.S. seems you're using SQL Server DB because of using `charindex()` function.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the response. This worked as well:  SELECT LEFT(RIGHT('ProviderPractice:ONGH_PROFILE_PRACTICE:14758:1194291922^190301^003',
   CHARINDEX(':',REVERSE('ProviderPractice:ONGH_PROFILE_PRACTICE:14758:1194291922^190301^003'))-1),
  CHARINDEX('^',RIGHT('ProviderPractice:ONGH_PROFILE_PRACTICE:14758:1194291922^190301^003',
   CHARINDEX(':', REVERSE('ProviderPractice:ONGH_PROFILE_PRACTICE:14758:1194291922^190301^003'))-1))
  )   +RIGHT('ProviderPractice:ONGH_PROFILE_PRACTICE:14758:1194291922^190301^003',3)

Comment: OK, you're welcome @SriY

Answer (score 0):

try this

> SELECT
>   regexp_matches('ProviderPractice:ONGH_PROFILE_PRACTICE:14758:1194291922^190301^003',
>   ':([0-9]{7,}^)[0-9]{6}([0-9]+)');